# Confused about rim and tyre size

Tags: tire, rims

I bought a Bicycle Shaped Object for nipping around town (bikes keep getting stolen around here so I bought a £30 second hand muddyfox energy 26 from gumtree).

I want to replace the mountain bike tyres with something better for the road. The specification is:

1. Rims: 26 x 1.75, alloy, 36H
2. Tyres: 24 x 2.10 MTB tyres

I'm really confused by the dimensions - how can a tyre with 24 inch in diameter fit on a rim which is 26 inch in diameter?

I plan to put Schwalbe-Marathon Plus or the Touring version on it: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Schwalbe-Marathon-SmartGuard-Endurance-Compound/dp/B004NOC8HM?th=1&psc=1

But I'm just not sure if it's the correct size (plus it's hard to find 24 inch tyres for road/touring bikes).

Comment: Is it possible the writing on the side wall of the tyre is wrong?   Can you please look for an ETRTO code on the tyre?  probably something like `54-559` or the other way around `559-54`

Comment: @Criggie thank you! They are 53-559 (26x1.95). I have no idea why their website says "Tyres: 24 x 2.10 MTB tyres". Would a 26x2.0 tyre fit? I really want to put a marathon plus tour 26x2.0 tyre on the bike.

Comment: @datguyray, you can post your own answer here, it is appreciated by most users as it finishes the question.

Comment: You should study up on [tire sizing systems](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wheel rims are 26", and your 559 ETRTO number confirms that.  These are very common so there's plenty of options out there.

Why your old sidewall says "tyre 24" I don't know.  It is either a mistake, or perhaps that is the brand name.  If so, that's a terrible name for a tyre brand.

To be absolutely and completely confident, take your old tyre or your front wheel to the shop.  When there, physically compare the new tyre with what you brought along, and it should be obvious if they're a good match or out by two inches.

Comment: Road-biased 26" tyres exist but are not common.   Continental have one `26" Grand Prix` which is fast but not very puncture resistant.  I got 5,000 km off a pair before there were patches of thread showing through on the rear.   They also have a 26" gatorskin which should be tougher.  Both are only 28mm, and that might be too narrow for your rim.

Comment: 26" tires may be more available where there are more unusual bikes, like online sellers who specialize in recumbent bikes/velomobiles, which often have 26" (rear) wheels.

Comment: Specialized had a tire in a 26" by 1.0 inch wide offering (called the FatBoy).  I used these when all I had was a 26" MTB and wanted a faster road machine using the MTB. Rated to 100 psi, I ran them at that and it was indeed very quick for what it was (a MTB).  These days, knowing what we know, for most riding these would be run at a lower pressure than 100, and they would be even faster.  I cannot find these available anymore, but if someone made something similar, I would recommend it.  26-inch is a a bit challenging to find a great variety in now, but there are some options out there.